# Most efficient alternative to making functions within a loop

Tags: javascript, performance, function

The function I want to create requires an access myObject.
Is it better to create the helper function inside the main function so I have access to myObject with the scope.

Or should I make the helper function outside of myFunction and pass myObject as a parameter?

EDIT: Could I get memory-leak problem with those methods?

```
//Method 1
var myFunction = function(myObject){
    var helper = function(i){
        return console.log(i,myObject[i]);
    }

    for(var i in myObject){
        var callback = helper(i);
    }
}

//Method 2
var myFunction = function(myObject){
    for(var i in myObject){
        var callback = helper(i,myObject);
    }
}

var helper = function(i,myObject){
    return console.log(i,myObject[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should edit the title, you're not asking for an alternative, you're asking ... I think, for performance comparisons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're asking for performance.

[Here is a jsperf to test it for you](http://jsperf.com/in-function-or-out-of-function-helper) (Yup, this exists and is very neat).

So in running the tests a bunch of times I note that neither method clearly wins. It's very close and almost certainly doesn't matter. I also note that on Windows 8.1, IE 11 blows Chrome out of the water, it's not even close - like by a factor of 20. That's a neat little result but not really indicative of real world code performance and likely we're just hitting an optimized case. Within IE the in-function version is a tiny-almost-irrelevant bit faster.

You can play with the inputs somewhat (for example I just passed in a small object, maybe a big one has different results), but I'm ready to call a preliminary **conclusion**: Don't worry about performance here. Use whichever one makes more sense for your specific case in terms of code clarity.

Comment: About your jsperf, myFunction declaration shouldn't be in the timed loop but in the preparation code. Check http://jsperf.com/in-function-or-out-of-function-helper/2

Answer (score 1):

Apart from performance benefit mentioned by George Mauer, I think it will be a good idea to keep it inside to keep global context clean.

Different functions can have their own helpers defined inside them with same name rather than having function1Helper, function2Helper... in the global context.

Comment: I assumed the whole thing was in an immediately invoked function to prevent it from going global but if not you're absolutely correct. Don't make global functions!